# a map between two expansions of a function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is there something remarkable about the following map between two kinds of expansion $f(x)=\sum_n f_n x^n$ and $\tilde{f}(x)=\sum_n \frac{f_n x^n}{n!}$ ?

Comment: @Eugene: your question seems vague.  It is possible to say *something* about the passage from an ordinary generating function to an exponential generating function, so the answer is yes.  But what is it that you really want to know?

Comment: It takes "division by x and ignoring the remainder" to differentiation; this is certainly a noteworthy algebraic property.

Comment: It can be modeled by a variation of the Laplace transform (or possibly its inverse). The details are left as an exercise... 

Comment: Motivation came from the star-product (Moyal-Weyl) algebras. It turned out that certain star-product can be represented just as a pointwise multiplication of functions if one passes from one kind of expansion to another one. The map is not local, but who cares if it allows to transform complicated star-product equations to algebraic ones for functions of commuting variables.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your motivation, but the passage between the two expansions is compatible with the theory of "$q$-integers".  Recall that an integer $n$ can be written as the sum $1+1+\cdots+1$ ($n$ times).  Its "$q$-analog" is the number $[n]_q = 1 + q + \cdots + q^{n-1}$.  This is $n$ when $q=1$ and $1$ when $q=0$.

Similarly, $n!$ has a $q$-analog given by $[n]_q! = \[1\]_q \cdot [2]_q \cdots [n]_q = (1) \cdot (1+q) \cdot (1+q+q^2) \cdots (1+q+\cdots +q^n)$.  If $q=1$ this is the usual factorial, and if $q=0$ it is simply $1$.

Thus if you consider $$f_q(x) = \sum \frac{f_n}{[n]_q!} x^n,$$ then $q=0$ corresponds to your $f$ and $q=1$ to your $\tilde{f}$.

There are some surprising extensions of a number of combinatorial objects to $q\neq 1$, see for example the [Wikipedia page on q-analogs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog) For example, if $\tilde{f}$ satisfies a differential equation, then $f$ satisfies an appropriate $q$-analog of it (this was effectively mentioned in one of the comments, as the $q$-derivative at $q=0$ is simply multiplication by $1/x$).

Comment: ? Can I define a flow with respect to q? a differential equation for the evolution in q?